# Drag and drop SVGs with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, svg, drag-and-drop, raphael

Looking for some advice (example would be great) on dragging and dropping SVGs using RaphaelJS.

I have found how to drag an object created withint Raphael

```
window.onload = function() {
var R = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500);    
var c = R.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
    fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
    stroke: "none",
    opacity: .5
});
var start = function () {
...
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
...
},
up = function () {
...
};
c.drag(move, start, up);    
};​
```

But I need to be able to adapt this to work with a seperate SVG file(s) so for example 
myPage.html has myImage.svg, I need to be able to drag myImage.svg around the 'canvas'.
I'm thinking something like

```
var c = R.SOMEMETHOD('myImage.svg');
...
c.drag(move, start, up);
```

For example.

Is there a way to do this and if so, an example would be brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

This magic method doesn't exist in RaphaelJS. But there is a way to accomplish this. You can have a look at [the raphael-svg-import project on GitHub](https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import) which works well for basic svgs

Then, you'll want to use a [grouping facility](https://github.com/trotter/raphael-groups) as you cannot use the Set functionnality of RaphaelJS

```
1 - import your SVG
2 - As you import, mark the elements so they belong to the same group
```

Enjoy !!